# How to avoid DIVIDE BY ZERO error in an SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle9i, divide-by-zero

```
SELECT  YEAR, period, round((1- sum(rej_qty) / sum(recd_qty))*100, 0)   
 FROM   TAB_A
 WHERE  sid = '200'
 AND    sdid IN ('4750')
 AND
(
       (
          YEAR ='2011'
       AND    period IN('01_JAN')
       )
OR
       (
          YEAR = '2010'
       AND    period IN('02_FEB','03_MAR','04_APR','05_MAY','06_JUN','07_JUL','08_AUG','09_SEP','10_OCT','11_NOV','12_DEC')
       )
)
group by year, period
```

For a particular month, recd_qty is ZERO because of which I am getting DIVIDE BY ZERO error.

Is there any way to avoid DIVIDE BY ZERO error?

I there any way where in that particular month is ignored?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to ignore such records you can use a subquery

```
SELECT  YEAR, period, round((1- rej_sum / recd_sum)*100, 0) FROM
(
  SELECT YEAR, sum(rej_qty) rej_sum, sum(recd_qty) recd_sum
  FROM   TAB_A
  WHERE  sid = '200'
  AND    sdid IN ('4750')
  AND
  (
       (
          YEAR ='2011'
       AND    period IN('01_JAN')
       )
  OR
  (
      YEAR = '2010'
       AND    period IN ('02_FEB','03_MAR','04_APR','05_MAY','06_JUN','07_JUL','08_AUG','09_SEP','10_OCT','11_NOV','12_DEC')
       )
  )
  group by year, period
)
WHERE recd_sum <> 0;
```

If you want to keep them and handle the division by zero issue, you can use decode or case

```
SELECT  YEAR, period, DECODE(recd_qty, 0, NULL, round((1- sum(rej_qty) / sum(recd_qty))*100, 0))
```

Comment: The `WHERE` clause would not solve the problem as he is summing `recd_qty`s before dividing.

Comment: @Tim Thanks, I've changed the SQL for a subquery

Comment: @Kenny That's the thing... it may not be accurate :)

Comment: It would be perfectly legal for Oracle to evaluate the expression in the SELECT list before evaluating the WHERE clause, so there is no guarantee that this would eliminate the error or that a future change to the query plan wouldn't cause the error to recur.  You'd need a DECODE/ CASE even if you use a subquery-- `SELECT year, period, (CASE WHEN recd_sum = 0 THEN null ELSE round((1 - rej_sum/ recd_sum)*100,0) END)`

Answer (score 27):

Have you tried using `NULLIF()`?

```
 SELECT
 ( 100 / NULLIF( 0, 0 ) ) AS value
 ;
```

Oracle Doc
http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/ANSIISOSQLSupport.php#NULLIFFunction

Another example
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/984-Using-NULLIF-To-Prevent-Divide-By-Zero-Errors-In-SQL.htm

Comment: SELECT
 ( 100 / NULLIF( 0, 0 ) ) AS value
 FROM DUAL;

to make it executable

Answer (score 5):

```
round(ISNULL(
((1- sum(rej_qty)) / NULLIF( (sum(recd_qty))*100), 0 )),
0
),0)
```

If you replace your division using NULLIF to set a NULL when there is divide by zero, then an ISNULL to replace the NULL with a 0 - or indeed whatever value you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

CASE WHEN sum(recd_qty) <> 0 THEN round((1- sum(rej_qty) / sum(recd_qty))*100, 0) ELSE 0 END